# System tray for Tiling window manager ( dwm )

Tags: dwm, tiling-wm

I am a noob at the tiling window manager installed dwm and it isn't shipped with the system tray.

How can I install those (battery, volume, network manager, etc.) and put it into the dwm bar or any tiling window bars?

Is there any way that I make a keyboard shortcut for it (like volume level or brightness level)? I also want to make it clickable like a desktop environment.

I tried searching the internet but could not find a helpful solution.

Comment: See this patch on DWM official site:
https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/systray/